# Python regex not matching

Tags: python, regex

Does anyone know why this regex isn't returning any matches?

```
local = u'Rua Engenheira Enedina Alves Marqu\xeas, 126 - Cajuru, Cajuru, Curitiba - PR'
p = re.compile(ur'\d[ ]+?-(.*?)(?:,|-)')
matches = re.match(p,local)
```

[Link to test](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5Cd%5B%20%5D%2B%3F-(.*%3F)(%3F%3A%2C%7C-)&test_string=Rua%20Engenheira%20Enedina%20Alves%20Marqu%C3%AAs%2C%20126%20-%20Cajuru%2C%20Cajuru%2C%20Curitiba%20-%20PR%20Engenheira%20Enedina%20Alves%20Marqu%C3%AAs&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

when I try this regex in any regex test tool it returns what I want, I this case I want to capture the word

> Cajuru

Comment: Hi, please take a look at thoose both websites (pythex)[https://pythex.org/] and (pyregex)[http://www.pyregex.com/].  They will be both really helpful for you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using [`re.match()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match), not [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search). `re.match()` *anchors to the start*.

Using `re.search()` works fine:

```
>>> local = u'Rua Engenheira Enedina Alves Marqu\xeas, 126 - Cajuru, Cajuru, Curitiba - PR'
>>> p = re.compile(ur'\d[ ]+?-(.*?)(?:,|-)')
>>> re.search(p, local)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x104dde288>
>>> re.search(p, local).group()
u'6 - Cajuru,'
```

See the [*`match()` vs. `search()`* section](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#match-versus-search) of the Python Regex HOWTO:

> The `match()` function only checks if the RE matches at the beginning of the string while `search()` will scan forward through the string for a match. It’s important to keep this distinction in mind. Remember, `match()` will only report a successful match which will start at 0; if the match wouldn’t start at zero, `match()` will not report it.

Note that you don't have to call the module level `re.search()` here; the compiled expression in `p` has a `search()` method too:

```
>>> p.search(local).group()
u'6 - Cajuru,'
```

Comment: thanks, I've read the link and got the difference. Now my code is working. =)